# Will (variable or {}) work crossbrowser in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, binary-operators

The `if(variable)` clause in the following constructs checks if list/array is not null/undefined, to avoid an exception:

```
if (list)
    for (var k in list) {
       ...

if (array)
    for (var i = array.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        ...
```

But JS syntax allows expressions like

```
null || []
undefined || {}
```

So I can make code shorter by one line and still check the array/object:

```
for (var k in obj || {}) {
    ...

for (var i = (array || {}).length; i >= 0; i--) {
    ...
```

The question essentially is: does `null/undefined || []/{}` expression return the latter in all browsers?

*edit:* found out that curly brackets are better for `for (var k in list || {})` iteration, because an array (square brackets) cause an iteration and an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, will all resolve to `false`, when treated as a boolean (which the `||` operator does), and so, all browser will use the latter. This behavior is perfectly safe.

Answer (score 2):

Yes

I hate the 15 char limit.

Comment: +1 for 15 char limit. altho it's not very related to the question, i agree emphatically, at least when it comes to comments